# Is there a way to register a limited amount of users in firebase in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am making an application where a particular area can have only 5 admins. Each time a new user is registered i need to check whether the area that he mentions has less than 5 admins. Otherwise he cannot register as an admin and has to use guest access.
My database looks like this-

```
Areas 
   -AreaName1 
      -Admin 
         -Admin1UID 
              -admin_name:"" 
              -admin_area:"" 
              -admin_email:"" 
         -Admin2UID 
              -admin_name:"" 
              -admin_area:""
              -admin_email:""
              .
              .
              .
```

---

So here is where i am stuck currently, please note that the colony_name variable is representing the area_name in the database
{

```
 mDatabase =
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Areas").child(colony_name).child("Admin");
                    final String finalColony_name = colony_name;
                    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            long numberOfAdmins = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                            if (numberOfAdmins < 5) {
                                registerUser(finalColony_name, email, password);
                            }else{
                                //DO NOT REGISTER USER
                            }
                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.i("onCancelled","called");
                        mRegProgress.dismiss();

                    }


                });

            }}
```

Whenever the if condition is false the OnCancelled method gets executed and it seems as though the else block is not present. There can be two cases here:

1. Either the user is registering with a new area name - In this
   case i want a new area to get created in the same format as given
   above.
2. The user is registering in a pre-loaded area but there are
       already 5 admins present and the pre-loaded area cannot have more
       than 5 admins

Here is the rest of the code for reference,

```
 private void registerUser(final String colony_name, final String email, String password) {
            Log.i("Registering", "Method Called");
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Log.d("LOG STATEMENT", "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Areas").child(colony_name).child("Admin");

                    final HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    userMap.put("admin_name", "default name");
                    userMap.put("admin_email", email);
                    userMap.put("admin_colony", (colony_name));

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString("colony_name_uid", (colony_name));
                    editor.putString("admin_rights", "true");
                    editor.apply();
                    editor.commit();


                    mDatabase.push().setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(mainIntent);

                                mRegProgress.dismiss();
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                mRegProgress.hide();
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Cannot sign in! Please check the                                          form or your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }
                    });


                }
            });
}
```

}

Comment: Because you say that `onCancelled()` method is called when the else statement should be called, what is `databaseError`?

Comment: No error ....it happens on its own. That is how it works actually